# Get server URL for Ember DS.Model Class

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

In using Ember Data for my models, there are some cases where I need to work around the data limitations and access other quasi-restful URLs on my server.

For example, I have a `Feed` object that records a stream of data. For accessing the models I have a RESTful endpoint:

```
/feeds/:feed_id
```

In order to start and stop recording a feed, I need to send a `PATCH` to a url like:

```
/feeds/:feed_id?update_action=start
```

Subsequently I can reload my model and see the changes reflected therein.

In this case, I need to access `$.ajax` and the URL is the same as the one Ember would use. However, I can't figure out how to eke this information out of Ember.

So far, the best I can do is:

```
DS.Model.reopen

  rootForModel: Ember.computed( ->
    @.store.adapterForType(@).serializer.rootForType(@.constructor)
  )

  pluralRootForModel: Ember.computed( ->
    @.store.adapterForType(@).serializer.pluralize(@get("rootForModel"))
  )
```

Such that for an instance of `App.FeedItem` I can do:

```
this.get("rootForModel") # feed_item
this.get("pluralRootForModel") # feed_items
```

And I'm guessing this would stay in sync with any settings made in the Adapter etc.

Subsequently, I can call like:

```
$.ajax
  url: @get("pluralRootForModel") + "/" + @get("id")
  data:
    update_action: "start"
  type: "PATCH"
```

Is this totally out in left field? Is there a more direct way to compose these URLs?

Another (related issue) is getting the underscored name for a given model.

```
App.MyModelController  => my_model_controller
```

I've done something like:

Ember.Object.reopenClass

```
###*
 * The underscored name for this.
 * i.e. App.MyClass -> my_class
 * From an instance, use this.constructor.underscored_class_name()
 * @return {String} This classname, underscored.
###
underscored_class_name: ->
  _.underscored("#{@}".replace(/^.*?\./g, ""))
```

Is this crazy? Are there any better ways?

Answer (score 3):

[Check out `buildURL` in `DS.RESTAdapter`](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#method_buildURL).

If you want to use underscores in server paths and keys, check out `DS.ActiveModelAdapter` (and its default serializer, `DS.ActiveModelSerializer`). This adapter has its own implementation of `buildURL`.

Comment: I settled on `DS.RESTAdapter.prototype.buildURL('my-model-type')`